# Mongo db - how to join and sort two collection with pagination

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have 2 collections:

1. Office -

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(someOfficeId),
  name: "some name",
  ..other fields
}
```

2. Documents -

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(SomeId),
  name: "Some document name",
  officeId: ObjectId(someOfficeId),
  ...etc
}
```

I need to get list of offices sorted by count of documetns that refer to office. Also should be realized pagination.

I tryied to do this by aggregation and using **$lookup**

```
const aggregation = [
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'documents',
                let: {
                    id: '$id'
                },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: ['$officeId', '$id']
                            },
                            // sent_at: {
                            //     $gte: start,
                            //     $lt: end,
                            // },
                        }
                    }
                ],
                as: 'documents'
            },
        },
        { $sortByCount:  "$documents" },
        { $skip: (page - 1) * limit },
        { $limit: limit },
    ];
```

But this doesn't work for me

Any Ideas how to realize this?

p.s. I need to show offices with 0 documents, so get offices by documets - doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- you can use [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#correlated-subqueries-using-concise-syntax) to join on that field, and pipeline to group so you count the documents of each office (instead of putting the documents into an array, because you only case for the count)
- `$set` is to get that count at top level field
- sort using the `noffices` field
- you can use the skip/limit way for pagination, but if your collection is very big it will be slow see [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/#pagination-example). Alternative you can do the pagination using the `_id` natural order, or retrieve more document in each query and have them in memory (instead of retriving just 1 page's documents)

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=71206147-m)

```js
offices.aggregate(
[{"$lookup":
  {"from":"documents",
   "localField":"_id",
   "foreignField":"officeId",
   "pipeline":[{"$group":{"_id":null, "count":{"$sum":1}}}],
   "as":"noffices"}},
 {"$set":
  {"noffices":
   {"$cond":
    [{"$eq":["$noffices", []]}, 0,
     {"$arrayElemAt":["$noffices.count", 0]}]}}},
 {"$sort":{"noffices":-1}}])
```

As the other answer pointed out you forgot the `_` of `id`, but you don't need the `let` or match inside the pipeline with `$expr`, with the above lookup. Also `$sortByCount` doesn't count the member of an array, you would need `$size` (sort by count is just group and count its not for arrays). But you dont need `$size` also you can count them in the pipeline, like above.

---

Edit

Query

- you can add in the pipeline what you need or just remove it
- this keeps all documents, and counts the array size
- and then sorts

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=71206147-1-m)

```js
offices.aggregate(
[{"$lookup":
  {"from":"documents",
   "localField":"_id",
   "foreignField":"officeId",
   "pipeline":[],
   "as":"alldocuments"}},
 {"$set":{"ndocuments":{"$size":"$alldocuments"}}},
 {"$sort":{"ndocuments":-1}}])
```

Comment: It looks awesome!

But I wanted to save full data of document in case if I need to do calculation with data of office -
for example add also for each office count of signed and not signed documents ( by field *signed*). I guess it possible to do on Mongo level - could you say me - where (how) I need to do this?

And one my worries - will it works good in case of thousands of offices and documents (of course with using pagination)?

Comment: i added one more query, i dont know what is your expected output, to be sure what you need, but the second query keeps all the documents, you can add your code in the pipeline that its empty now, or after the lookup

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your lookup

While passing the variable in with `$let`. You forgot the `_` of the `$_id` local field

```
let: {
    id: '$id'
},
```

In the `$exp`, since you are using a variable `id` and not a field of the
`Documents` collection, you should use `$$` to make reference to the variable.

```
$expr: {
    $eq: ['$officeId', '$$id']
},
```